# Pandas read_excel usecols parameter: Pycharm requires int

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Pycharm (v2022.2) is complaining about the `usecols` input parameter of `pd.read_excel`. It requires a single `int` value. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) on the other hand clearly states that a `list-like or callable` is allowed.

I used to use something like this before and the code actually works as expected:

```
pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", usecols="A:C")  # Pycharm: Expected type 'int', got 'str' instead
```

Also, it is not possible to use a `list` of `int`:

```
pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", usecols=[1, 2, 3])  # Pycharm: Expected type 'int', got 'list[int]' instead
```

Is this a bug in Pycharm or did I do anything wrong?

Comment: i want to know why, too

Comment: Pycharm will complain but it's just its own inspector, the code should still run fine. Just tested on Py3.11, Pandas 2.1.4, PyCharm 2023.2.1. Probably worth filing it with either PyCharm issues forum or Pandas issues